# how can we automate requests in JMeter for flex applications?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have been working on flex application and wanted to automated requests through Jmeter. If it is possible to automate requests through Jmeter. 
The application has its backend developed in JAVA and front end is Flex would be a great help if there is any possible way out for this

Answer (score 1):

If its a web application and can be accessed via a web browser, I'd prefer to use Blazemeter (Chrome Extension).

I would record my test script using Blazemeter and then export the test plan (jmx file).

And then simply open that test plan in Jmeter, make changes if required, increase/decrease threads and add listeners. Then, save the test plan and hit run...

Comment: Can you share any working example, as this would help me to dig down for actual implementation

Comment: Can you share the link for your application? I will try and make a working example of that for you!!

Comment: It would'nt be possible to share the application itself is on intranet server.

Comment: Well i have tried using blaze meter it shows JMX inactive even after completing the whole process you mentioned above

Comment: Were you logged in to Blazemeter?

Comment: Yes i was logged in !

Comment: Can you write a proper flow of what you did so that I can get an idea of what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Okay, I just logged in the application and entered domains to follow (URL), enabled follow me and then started recording

Comment: What I usually do is, 1. Log in. 2. Start recorder. 3. Browser the site. 4. Stop recorder. 5. Download the JMX file. What you did differently is you activated the Follow Me (I haven't tried it and don't know what it does) and you didn't stop recorder before trying to download the JMX file. Stop the recorder after browser and then try to download JMx file. If that doesn't work, try the way I do it and see if it gets the result you are looking for.